# graphql: adding an entry removes the previous one

Tags: graphql, strapi

I'm using graphql plugin with Strapi cms. I'm trying to add a new collection (called Exam) and associate it with another collection (called Subjects). 
Each time I perform the mutation, the new Exam collection replaces the previous added Exam collection, instead of adding it to the array of associated collection in Subject.

Here is my graphql code:

```
mutation {
    createExam(input: {
      data: {
        name: "newExam",
        subjects: ["5c47906ad9dc"]
      }
    }) {
      exam {
        name
      }
    }
  }
```

When performing this mutation a few times with different Exam names, I would expect the subject with _id 5c47906ad9dc to have an array of associated Exam collections, but instead it's left only with the last mutation (ie one collection)

When I'm using Strapi to manually add many Exam collections to the Subject, it's working without issues.

What could be the problem? I'm not sure what additional information I should provide

Thanks in advance